# How to describe a job on linkedin without overinflating and underselling it?

Tags: linkedin, title

I come across so many LinkedIn job titles and job descriptions that make me roll my eyes or which I think aren't even true that I'm wondering what I should put there myself.

My position (the position named in my work contract) is "team leader" in department A. The whole field A at my company is divided into only 3 big teams. I manage one of them. Each team has a different thematic focus (a different function). Mine is B.

Would the description "head of B" (or "managing B") be untruthful or pretentious? I want to be truthful, but also avoid underselling myself.

If the question is too specific: what are the best practices to name your job on linkedin and similar networks?

I think it's a workplace question since I'm mainly worried about the impression my profile will make in professional contexts: on my coworkers, recruiters, etc.

Comment: Do you have any examples of these eye-rolling titles? Depending on your country, industry etc., they might be quite ordinary.

Comment: "Lead" is very common in software

Comment: @Kozaky, one of my colleagues has "head of [a very small field C] at [company]". He's just a project manager in a team of about 6 project managers without responsibility over other people and yes, his tasks mainly lie in C, but not exclusively. Some of my friends are "visionaries". Some just list all their degrees: "Adam Smith, PhD. (Physics), M.Sc. (Maths), M.Sc. (Psych.), B.A. (Physics).

Comment: From what i see on LinkedIn and know from the real life on same people, everyone use words to make it seam more than it actually is, without actually lying. Unfortunately it is also why LinkedIn readers take it in to the account. Just try to keep your descriptions single-meaning :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you want to be consistent with your job title, be it in your CV or LinkedIn. You also usually want to use the same job title that you officially had in your old job. If the recruter calls your references you want them to agree with the job title you advertise.

That said you also want to sell yourself. Do not downplay the importance of your role by fear of sounding pompous. In your example, both "Team Leader" and "Head of B" would probably be ok. If you think that mentioning B is a good marketing point go for the later.

Bottom line is, people do sometimes roll their eyes when looking at grandiose job titles. But they still pick up the phone and call.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't agree with your 2nd and 3rd paragraphs - if we were to say that "B" was for example "e-commerce" then saying "Head of e-commerce" has entirely different connotations from "e-commerce development team leader". And personally if I saw a grandiose or inflated job title on linkedin then.. no I wouldn't still call. In fact it may well be enough to nudge me over to the side of binning the applicant.

Comment: @motosubatsu What do you consider grandiose or inflated job titles? Depending on the company both the titles you mention can be used for the same position. If a recruiter was looking for a leader in e-commerce he would definitely consider both titles even if you maybe consider the first to be inflated. I also wouldn't assume OP is working in software development as the question can be answered in a general fashion.

Comment: @motosubatsu, correct me if I'm wrong - English is not my first language. But doesn't "e-commerce development team leader" mean that I'm one of the "e-commerce development team leaders"? In my case, using your example, I'm the only person controlling "e-commerce development". Or more exactly, my team is.

Comment: I would say grandiose or inflated if the title doesn't reflect the candidates actual role and responsibilities - to be fair I'd only really consider it a *really* bad thing if it didn't match what their references said. So saying that I wouldn't call was possibly a touch hyperbolic. But if someone claimed to be "Head of" a function when their described role was that of a Team Lead I'd be extremely skeptical of their candidacy

Comment: @421567788 There may be a little bit of a language barrier or cultural variation, so I apologize if this isn't the clearest - I wouldn't assume that "e-commerce team leader" (to stick with the example) meant there was more than one team, unless the organization was very large. To be honest job titles are largely irrelevant - what's actually important is as Bobsleigh says, the title you "advertise" **must** match what your employer is going to say it is on a reference, all else is secondary.

Comment: Funnily enough I actually had the job title "e-commerce manger" once - although in reality the role would have been called CTO anywhere else if I'd actually tried to *claim* that on Linkedin etc I'd have looked like a liar as soon as they checked my references, stick to what your title  **is** and describe your responsibilities accurately and you won't go far wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> Would the description "head of B" (or "managing B") be untruthful or pretentious? I want to be truthful, but also avoid underselling myself.

Yep and Yep. Sorry but both of those are examples of the eyeroll-inducing inflated titles you mention because you aren't either of those things - you're a team lead, which is nothing to be embarrassed about! If you want to include a reference to the specialty (ie. "B") then say you're the

> "B" Team Lead

Which is accurate, gets the specialty across and isn't underselling yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'm a big fan of just being straight forward. List your title as it is in your company. Don't complicate it and don't try to pad it. I'm a technical lead at a small company, so often I get pulled in to do some filtering on applications and the things that turn me off the most, is business speak, jargon and inflated titles. I'm looking for genuine folks to work with. It also points to a "cut and paste" mindset where individuals tend to grab something from the internet and paste it into their resume and often those sorts of solutions are not preferable. Take this with a grain of salt, often I make my final decision at the interview.